# Compress char data

Tags: c, compression

I have a 5 x 10 `char` matrix and I am suppose to compress it like a run length encoding.

```
    printf("Enter your data (5x10) of characters: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE2; j++)
        scanf("%c", &matrix2[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
    compress(matrix2);
    break;  

void compress(char data[SIZE1][SIZE2])
{
    int row, column, count=1;
    for (row = 0; row < SIZE1; row++)
    {
        for (column = 0; column < SIZE2; column++)
        {
            if (data[row][column] == data[row][column + 1])
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c%d", data[row][column], count);
                count = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code but I do not understand why my output will always have a 1 in front. 
Input:

```
aaabbbcccd
aabbccddee
aaaaaaaaaa
abcabcabca
aaabbbcccc
```

output:

```
a3b3c3d1
1a2b2c2d2e2
1a10
1a1b1c1a1b1c1a1b1c1a1
1a3b3
```

expected output:

```
a3b3c3d1
a2b2c2d2e2
a10
a1b1c1a1b1c1a1b1c1a1
a3b3c4
```

Comment: There is a new line character (`\n`) before the 1.

Comment: So.. I take it you're *not* using `fgets()` when reading these from input and stripping the trailing newline?

Comment: nope, its just a normal scanf function to read the matrix and compress the data. how do I remove the newline?

Comment: IMO, this code wouldn't work because the function won't get SIZE1 and SIZE2; because the function receives a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: `data[row][column + 1]` is likely examining things it probably shouldn't be, due to your loop constraint...

Answer (score 2):

It is counting the newline character too.

Comment: The OP edited the input. Now it is counting the line feed :).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the commenters are suggesting a change like so:

```
    printf("Enter your data (5x10) of characters: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE2; j++)
        scanf("%c", &matrix2[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
    compress(matrix2);
    break;  

void compress(char data[SIZE1][SIZE2])
{
    int row, column, count=1;
    for (row = 0; row < SIZE1; row++)
    {
        for (column = 0; column < SIZE2; column++)
        {
            if (data[row][column] == data[row][column + 1])
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (data[row][column] != '\n')
                {
                    printf("%c%d", data[row][column], count);
                    count = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the data entry.  Have it deal with `\n` and error detection.

```
printf("Enter your data (%dx%d) of characters: \n", SIZE1, SIZE2);
for (i = 0; i < SIZE1; i++) {
  char buffer[(SIZE2 + 2)*2];  // Consider IO buffers 2x the needed size
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) 
    Handle_EndOfFileOrIOError();

  size_t len = strlen(buffer);
  if (len != SIZE2+1 || buffer[len-1] != '\n') 
    Handle_UnexpectDataLengthError(buffer, len);

  for (j = 0; j < SIZE2; j++) {
    matrix2[i][j] = buffer[j];
  }
  // or simply memcpy(matrix2[i], buffer, SIZE2);

printf("\n");
compress(matrix2);
break;
```

Comment: Because I am new to programming and I have not learn buffer, is there any way to detect the "\n" and prevent it from entering the array? Because the problem is that the "\n" is considered in the array and my last 4 numbers are not recorded in the array.